# Camera onPreviewFrame not called

Tags: android, video, camera

when using the Camera.PreviewCallback implementation the onPreviewFrame is called without problem after initializing camera and starting preview (Camera.startPrevew()). The problem is if I make a video recording using MediaRecorder onPreviewFrame does not get called any more.

I understand that when using MediaRecorder to record video stops the Camera.PreviewCallback, but why can't it be restarted?

I have tried resetting the camera preview callback (setPreviewCallback(callback)) and restarting startPreview, but while I have a preview there is no call to onPreviewFrame.

Comment: did you find normal solution for it?

Answer (score 17):

You must call setPreviewCallback in the surfaceChanged method, not only in the surfaceCreated.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
  return;
}

try {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
} catch (Exception e){
  // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
}

try {
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    mCamera.startPreview();

} catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: you can't call `mCamera.stopPreview();`,  `mCamera.startPreview();` after `MediaRecorder.start` otherwise app won't respond when you try to stop recording `MediaRecorder.stop`.

Comment: anyway your answer is weird because it's not about SurfaceView or TextureView at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314822/video-recording-and-onpreviewframe-callback-at-the-same-time

Comment: we're talking about `onPreviewFrame` callback and not about video visualization on some view (SurfaceView or TextureView).

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem; see

[setOneShotPreviewCallback not hitting onPreviewFrame() in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404599/setoneshotpreviewcallback-not-hitting-onpreviewframe-in-callback/16574244#16574244)

What I discovered was that after calling `Camera#unlock()` to prepare the `MediaRecorder`, it was necessary to call `Camera#reconnect()` before setting the preview callback.  This is because `Camera.unlock()` detaches the camera from the process to let the `MediaRecorder` connect to it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#unlock()

In my investigations I also discovered that if you set any preview callbacks using other methods than the one shot method, you have to reset all of these after calling `Camera#reconnect()` as well.  So, briefly:

```
mCamera.unlock();
//set up MediaRecorder
mCamera.reconnect();
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mCallback);
//or whatever callback method you want to use
//and even if you've set this callback already
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This solved my problem.  I was calling `lock()` instead of `reconnect()`.

Comment: `mCamera.reconnect();` if you do this and try to start MediaRecorder you will get exception...

Comment: I tried it also after `MediaRecorder.start` - doesn't work

Comment: didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314822/video-recording-and-onpreviewframe-callback-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 3):

You should call it within new instantiation of previewCallBacks() interface, like below

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // if (mediaRecorder == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense, you didn't understand the question, frames won't be send after MediaRecorder.start

Answer (score 0):

You need to call startPreview() again after a video or photo was taken.

Comment: **after** - do you hear yourself? question is how to record and get frames at the same time, not **after**!